# How to add and remove (multiple) image from canvas.?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new to canvas (HTML5) i have to design a paint application on canvas. There is a feature like dynamic addition of the selected image at canvas (on mouse-movements) and functionality to delete and drag that added image (Same for Text addition). Now my Question is how can we delete the images from the canvas (Note :There are no fixed no. of images added to the canvas.) Can you please suggest me the approach ??

Comment: Have you looked into canvas libraries like [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/)?

Comment: yes i have seen that one . But enough tutorial is not present for that library . :(

Answer (score 18):

An HTML5 Canvas is much like a real-world canvas. When you draw to the canvas the ink changes the canvas, blending with the other contents already there and forever changing them.

Ask Monet *"How do you add a new person to your painting?"* and he might say *"you just paint them where you want them!"* Similarly, you use [`drawImage()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage) to 'paint' an image to your Canvas.

However, if you ask Monet *"How do you **remove** a person from a painting?"* and he would likely look at you funny and then respond *"Quoi? You would have to either make a new painting, or else paint over top of the person!"* Similarly, if you want to "remove" something from your canvas you either have to start over (clear the canvas and draw everything except that thing) or re-paint what was 'behind' your image on top of it.

[Here is an example I made](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_copy.html) that shows one way that you can 'save' part of a canvas (by drawing it to another canvas) and then later drawing it back over something to 'erase' it.

However, I generally advise you not to use an HTML5 Canvas unless you know why you need it. You mention adding and removing items, and also detecting mouse movements. Using a *retained-mode* drawing system—like HTML or SVG—means that you actually add or remove or change items in an object representation, and it is up to someone else (the browser) to figure out how to best redraw them.

You may be best served by letting the "paint" portions of the user input be done on one or more canvases, and then compositing these canvases with other items (such as `<div>`s with text, or `<img>` for pictures, or vector-based SVG artwork).

You can make your own retained-mode system on type of canvas, or you can use someone else's library that does this. But instead I'd suggest that you consider whether this is the best and easiest way to accomplish your goals.

Comment: This is one of the best answers i saw at SO. +1.