# How I can find which grid square element I clicked in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I have drawn a grid in html5 canvas using StrokeLineX and StrokeLineY. I want to highlight the particular square/rectangle when I click on it in the grid.
I have tried using math.floor to define an index for a space but as soon as the width or height increases it starts giving different answers. I have tried too many times before finally posting it here. 
Here is the code.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      canvas.addEventListener('click', on_canvas_click, false);
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      var tray_length = 800;
      var tray_depth = 800;
      var boxHeight = 50;
      var boxWidth = 50;

var canvas_X = tray_length;
      var canvas_Y = tray_depth;

      var box_x_pixels = canvas_X/no_of_columns;
      var box_y_pixels = canvas_Y/no_of_rows;

// Drawing the grid
      for (var y = boxWidth; y < canvas_Y; y += boxWidth) {
          strokeLineX(ctx, y);
      }

      for (var x = boxHeight; x < canvas_X; x += boxHeight) {
              strokeLineY(ctx, x);

          }

function strokeLineX(ctx, y) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
          ctx.moveTo(0, y);
          ctx.lineTo(canvas_X, y);
          ctx.stroke();
          ctx.closePath();
      }



      function strokeLineY(ctx, x) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
          ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
          ctx.lineTo(x, canvas_Y);
          ctx.stroke();
          ctx.closePath();
      }

function on_canvas_click(ev) {
          var x = ev.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
          var y = ev.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

          console.log(x+":"+y);
          var coordinateDisplay = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;

            if (y>= 0 && y <= y+boxHeight ) {    

                var indexOfX = Math.floor(x/boxWidth); //divide on width and round off
                var indexOfY = Math.floor(y/boxHeight);
                // alert('You clicked bar index: ' + indexOfX+"-"+indexOfY);


               ctx.fillRect="green";
               ctx.rect(x,y,box_x_pixels,box_y_pixels);
               ctx.stroke();

                console.log(indexOfX + "-" + indexOfY);


            }


      }
```

Comment: Where are `box_x_pixels, box_y_pixels` defined?

Comment: And why do you calculate `indexOfX, indexOfY` if they're never used?

Comment: I am using it to calculate the coordinates to know where i clicked using console.log

Comment: [Creating a Clickable Grid in a Web Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140101/creating-a-clickable-grid-in-a-web-browser/59555920#59555920) might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `on_canvas_click` change the following:

Instead of

```
    ctx.fillRect="green";
```

do:

```
    ctx.fillStyle="green";
```

And instead of:

```
    ctx.rect(x,y,box_x_pixels,box_y_pixels);
```

do:

```
    ctx.fillRect(boxWidth*indexOfX, boxHeight*indexOfY, boxWidth, boxHeight);
```

... and you don't need:

```
    ctx.stroke();
```

Here is a working snippet with those changes applied, but also with some simplifications which are unrelated to your problem:

- Removal of unused variables;
- Use of one function to draw lines, instead of two;
- Use of `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` properties;
- Drawing grid lines also on the outer grid boundaries

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var boxHeight = 50;
var boxWidth = 50;
var canvas_X = canvas.width;
var canvas_Y = canvas.height;

canvas.addEventListener('click', on_canvas_click, false);

// Drawing the grid
for (var y = 0; y <= canvas_Y; y += boxWidth) {
    strokeLine(ctx, 0, y, canvas_X, y, 'green');
}

for (var x = 0; x <= canvas_X; x += boxHeight) {
    strokeLine(ctx, x, 0, x, canvas_Y, 'red');
}

function strokeLine(ctx, x0, y0, x1, y1, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
    ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function on_canvas_click(ev) {
    var x = ev.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = ev.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    if (y>= 0 && y <= y+boxHeight ) {    
        var indexOfX = Math.floor(x/boxWidth); //divide on width and round off
        var indexOfY = Math.floor(y/boxHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle="green";
        ctx.fillRect(boxWidth*indexOfX, boxHeight*indexOfY, boxWidth, boxHeight);
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks trincot. It solved the problem. My canvas element is drawn roughly around 160 pixel from top that is why my results for indexofX and indexofY variable were coming wrong as I was not subtracting the top from my current position

Comment: You're welcome. To be honest, the problem was more than that: you used two pairs of variables for box sizes (e.g. `boxWidth` versus `box_x_pixels`), which were incompatible. You used the one to draw the grid, and the other to (try to) fill the rectangle.