# Is it really needed to use third-party libraries to put a simple textbox in a <canvas>?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to put **textboxes** (that can be edited) on a HTML5 canvas. 
(Example : like in a "Paint" software, you can create textboxes).

Is it really needed to use third-party libraries such as 
https://github.com/claydotio/Canvas-Input in order to do such a basic thing?
Isn't there no simple solution for creating textboxes in a HTML5 canvas?

*If so, is there are a library (for Textbox inside ) that is considered as standard?*

Comment: A third party wouldn't be able to do it either if it required a third party library.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get it ? :)

Comment: If a third party library was necessary to do what you want, how would the first third party library ever work? Libraries are built with standard code anyone can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, canvas is a bitmap and has no support for controls or DOM elements such as input boxes.

All the logic for that must be made manually by simulating such a functionality.

You can take a look at my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011931/i-am-trying-to-edit-text-on-canvas/21011975#21011975) for one way of doing this.

Comment: How would you do then to add inputboxes on a canvas ?

Comment: @Basj see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011931/i-am-trying-to-edit-text-on-canvas/21011975#21011975